# Not able to click on deivce Menu button using appium in android

Tags: automated-testing, android, appium

I am working on automation of mobile native app using Appium in Java language. I want to click on device Menu button.

**Method 1:**

```
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 js.executeScript("mobile: keyevent", 82);
```

tried but not working.

**Method 2:-**

```
HashMap swipeObject = new HashMap();
swipeObject.put("keycode", 82);
((JavascriptExecutor ) driver).executeScript("mobile: keyevent", swipeObject);
```

and

```
driver.execute_script("mobile: keyevent", {"keycode": 82})
```

this is not working,can any one help me on this.

Comment: You should use applium sendkey method , Like : AppiumDriver.sendKeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.MENU) OR driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(AndroidKeys.MENU);

Comment: i am using webdriver..is it ok for it

Comment: Yes of course. It is ok with appium + webdriver.

Comment: code is same which I have shared as comment. Once you confirm that it is working then sure i will post as answer.

Comment: code is required for click device menu bar at top right.

Comment: Not getting you..can you please explain in detail? is that your app menu or android screen menu??

Comment: android device screen menu bar for cilckable

Comment: then it should work : driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(AndroidKeys.MENU)

Comment: and its menu has two sub menus X and Y.

Comment: Please try :   HashMap swipeObject = new HashMap(); swipeObject.put("keycode", 82);

 ((JavascriptExecutor ) driver).executeScript("mobile: keyevent", swipeObject);

Comment: not working..it throughs. error: not yet implemented

Answer (score 1):

Appium Java-client provides mechanism to Send a key event to the device.  Please check the [here](http://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidDeviceActionShortcuts.html) for more details. So for latest appium java client, below code should work.

```
  driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.MENU);
```

Comment: Can you please explain what trick does this do?

Comment: I don't think it as trick, Appium Java-client provides mechanism to Send a key event to the device. Please check this...http://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidDeviceActionShortcuts.html

Comment: Adding this explanation and the reference link to your answer would me more helpful for Narendra as well as other people having similar query! Some reason as to why this would work and why it is a better option over any other (if available) really helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest working solution is to use the `KEYCODE` KeyEvent:

```
adb shell input keyevent <KEYCODE_MENU>
```

[Help - Android keycode](http://thecodeartist.blogspot.in/2011/03/simulating-keyevents-on-android-device.html)

Comment: can you expand on why this is a good solution?

Comment: @Eciurleo - 
1 This is shell command. 
2 It will directly intended to communicate with device
3 Utility included in android sdk itself
Due to above all, success percentage may increase than other methods. This was my criteria for simplest solution :)

Comment: sounds good, can you add that into your answer using the edit?  Most users find it helpful to include the logic and background as to why a solution is the preferred one rather than just giving a solution :)

Comment: sure @ECiurleo , but waiting to know if it works for RaMeSh

Comment: people accept answers based on the answer itself, not the comments.   The comments should be a mechanism to improve the answer only.